# Can a Chrome App use Chrome's Password Manager?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have an app which allows connections to multiple servers. At the moment I'm storing all connection details except the password using chrome.storage.sync.

Is it possible to store username/password combinations using the standard built-in password manager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to store username/password combinations **using the standard built-in password manager**?

**In short, no.** There is no API to work with password storage of Chrome.

---

How to do authentication in a Chrome extension anyway? Here's an [old question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265348/storage-of-passwords-in-google-chrome-extension).

What changed since then is that Chrome has now a dedicated API for OAuth, [`chrome.identity`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity), which provides a secure way of logging onto web services.

However, if you're looking to make something like a local password manager, then you cannot really protect against a malicious user. All storage you can access, and all encryption/decryption functions, are available for a user to inspect.

A server component that handles a certain decryption step is a good measure, but not always applicable.

Edit: as suggested by Vloz, a [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) module that handles crypto functions is a good step to obfuscate data.

Comment: You can make hidden encrypt functions using native client. But i agree with you.