# Chrome extension - Get login credentials from page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im building a Chrome externsion which stores the user's passwords.

Is there a deterministic way to get the user's credentials under the assumption that the email input has a type Email and the passwords has a type Password?

```
<input type="email" />
<input type="password" />
```

What Ive tried so far is just taking the values of these fields using jQuery.
The issue is that I dont know when he actually submits the login.

Listening to url changes (using  `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` is not helpful because the user can either just press Back, go to a different url or submit the login).

Is there a way to get these credentials whenever:

- Chrome alerts the user about new account+password
- Chrome alerts the user about modified password

Comment: You can look at the source code of other password manager's extensions like Dashlane and LastPass.

Comment: Its a good idea but im afried they will probably be uglified. dont you think?

Comment: @tildedash Ive checked LastPass. they are manually want you to store Web + user + password

Comment: Dashlane saves it automatically, you could check the source code. If the code is obfucasted you can use http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: AFAIK, it's possible to get email address using [`getProfileUserInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) method of [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity). With regards to saving the password, you can use `chrome.privacy.services` with property `passwordSavingEnabled` set to true wherein if enabled, the password manager will ask if you want to save passwords (haven't tried though, how to possibly save the password). Suggested solution in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268993) might help.

Comment: Also, note that OAuth provides a mechanism for users to grant access to private data without sharing their private credentials (username/password). See this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) for more information.